# After calling features file in single feature, in report it is not printing or differentiate scenarios defined in called feature

Tags: karate

I called all the multiple features in single feature file and execute the same. It is not showing or printing the scenario counts available in all features in report, it is showing only single scenario defined in main feature where we call others.
Is there any way to print the scenarios as well listed in nested features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the built-in reports in the latest 1.0 release. It should at least show nested features.

Otherwise, yes - this is the expected behavior. If you want to change this kindly contribute code, or switch to another tool - thanks.

Comment: @karate I have seen one commend quit() and its description say like "unless the driver instance was created before entering the Scenario". Is it possible for you to brief me more about this line. As bit confused here.

Comment: @SaurabhGarg ask a new question please, and it looks like you never up-vote answers. right ?

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have raised the new question now. and for up-vote, I did where ever I found.